# Filter/Selected row after sorting doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an app which displays the list of documents. When you click the record of list, you have content of the selected document on the right side of the app (according to the attached printscreen). The list can be easily filtered by date. Everything is working fine.

But FIRST problem arise when users try select a row after they sorted the data. Gridview selects the row that was at the clicked index before it got sorted.

I've got that problem solved, by following code:

```
this.dTabCWoodHeadArodes.DefaultView.Sort = e.Condition;
this.dTabCWoodHeadArodes = this.dTabCWoodHeadArodes.DefaultView.ToTable(true);
```

Sorting works now, BUT then filter doesn't work after sorting (list remains unchanged).

Full source code:

```
private void c1TrueDBGridHead_AfterSort(object sender, C1.Win.C1TrueDBGrid.FilterEventArgs e)
        {
            this.dTabCWoodHeadArodes.DefaultView.Sort = e.Condition;
            this.dTabCWoodHeadArodes = this.dTabCWoodHeadArodes.DefaultView.ToTable(true);
            this.c1TrueDBGridHead.SelectedRows.Clear();
            if (this.c1TrueDBGridHead.RowCount > 0)
            {
                this.c1TrueDBGridHead.SelectedRows.Add(0);
                this.c1TrueDBGridHead.Row = 0;
            }
            this.c1TrueDBGridHead.Refresh();
        }
```

For me, it's a funny thing (and frustrating), because when I deactivate the following part of code:

```
this.dTabCWoodHeadArodes.DefaultView.Sort = e.Condition;
this.dTabCWoodHeadArodes = this.dTabCWoodHeadArodes.DefaultView.ToTable(true);
```

filter doesn't working.

On the other hand, when i deactivate:

```
this.c1TrueDBGridHead.SelectedRows.Clear();
if (this.c1TrueDBGridHead.RowCount > 0)
{
    this.c1TrueDBGridHead.SelectedRows.Add(0);
    this.c1TrueDBGridHead.Row = 0;
}
this.c1TrueDBGridHead.Refresh();
```

Filter working fine, but display selected document after sorting doesn't work...

I don't now how to fix it...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPxM3.png)

Comment: Is the issue that after sorting if a user makes a selection you don't get the value you expected? Or is the issue that if they had something selected then filtered the selection appears incorrect?

Comment: I see no reason for creating a new DataTable and it is likely this source of the problem.  Try commenting out `this.dTabCWoodHeadArodes = this.dTabCWoodHeadArodes.DefaultView.ToTable(true);`

Comment: @amura.cxg 

The main problem is that I don't get correct value after sorting. 

I added `this.dTabCWoodHeadArodes.DefaultView.Sort = e.Condition;
this.dTabCWoodHeadArodes = this.dTabCWoodHeadArodes.DefaultView.ToTable(true);` to code and that solve the problem BUT then filter doesn't work correctly :/

Comment: @TnTinMn exactly this part of code solved the problem of sorting BUT at the expense of filter.